# Implicit declaration of function // Problem with a createString function

Tags: c, list, function, struct, implicit

Hey Guys i need your help. I am learning for my C-exam in two days. For that i had written a little code for a simple list.
My Problem is that i get every time the same error: "implicit declaration of function 'copyString'". Can you tell me what mistakes i made.

In Germany we say: "Liebe Grüße"

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h> 
    #include <string.h>

    struct listen{
        int id; 
        int wert; 

        char *namen; 
        char *strasse; 
        int plz;

        struct listen *next; 
    }; 

    typedef struct listen elem; 

    elem *createElem(int id, int wert){

        elem* newElem = (elem*)malloc(sizeof(elem)); 

        if(newElem == NULL) printf("War nischt!"); 

        newElem->id = id; 
        newElem->wert = wert; 
        newElem->namen = NULL; 
        newElem->strasse = NULL; 
        newElem->plz = 0;

        return newElem;  

    }

    int stringLen(char* len){
        int d=0; 

        while(*len++) d++; 

        return d; 
    }
    
    char *createStr(char* st)
    {
        char* newSt;
        
        newSt = (char*)malloc(stringLen(st)+1);

        if(newSt == NULL) {printf("Fehler");};

        copyString(st, newSt); 

        return newSt;  
    }
    
    void copyString(char *von, char *nach)
    {
        while(*von!='\0')
        {
            *nach=*von; 

            *von++; 
            *nach++; 
        }

        *nach = '\0'; 
    }
    
    elem* addToList(elem *list, int wert, char* namen, char* strasse, int plz)
    {

        elem* p = createElem(list->id, wert); 

        p->namen = createStr(namen); 
        p->strasse = createStr(strasse); 
        p->plz = plz; 

        list->id++;
        p->next = list->next; 
        list->next = p;  

        return list; 
    }

    elem* createList(){

        elem* liste = createElem(0, 0); 

        return liste; 
    }

    void PrintElem(Elem *E)
    {
    printf("ID: %d | Wert: %d | Name : %s | Strasse: %s | PLZ: %d", E->id, E->wert, E->namen, E->strasse, E->plz); 
    }

    void printList(elem* list){

        printf("Liste:"); 
        while(list->next != NULL)
        {
            printElem(list->next); 
            list = list->next; 
        }
    }

    int main(){

        elem* Liste01 = createList(); 

        Liste01 = addToList(Liste01, 4, "Peter", "Lustigweg", 15834); 

        printList(Liste01);

        return 0;  
    }
```

I tried  rearranging the declared functions.

Comment: You call `copyString` in `createStr`, before is it declared/defined. Either move `copyString` to be defined before `createStr`, or add a declaration before `createStr` with the function prototype: `void copyString(char *von, char *nach);`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code to print out the odds and evens in a range.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_evens(int start, int stop) {
  if (start > stop) return;

  if (start % 2 == 0) {
    printf("Even: %d\n", start);
    print_odds(start+1, stop);
  }
  else {
    print_odds(start, stop);
  }
}

void print_odds(int start, int stop) {
  if (start > stop) return;

  if (start % 2 == 1) {
    printf("Odd: %d\n", start);
    print_evens(start+1, stop);
  }
  else {
    print_evens(start, stop);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  print_evens(1, 10);
}
```

This will give me the same kind of error you're facing. The `print_evens` function doesn't know that `print_odds` works. If we switch them around, we get the same problem the other way around.

The solution is to forward declare our functions and then *implement* them. This way we can also make `main` the first function we implement.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_evens(int start, int stop);
void print_odds(int start, int stop);

int main(void) {
  print_evens(1, 10);
}

void print_evens(int start, int stop) {
  if (start > stop) return;

  if (start % 2 == 0) {
    printf("Even: %d\n", start);
    print_odds(start+1, stop);
  }
  else {
    print_odds(start, stop);
  }
}

void print_odds(int start, int stop) {
  if (start > stop) return;

  if (start % 2 == 1) {
    printf("Odd: %d\n", start);
    print_evens(start+1, stop);
  }
  else {
    print_evens(start, stop);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code, and as noted in the good comments above, the "copyString" function needs to be moved before its usage within the "createStr" function.  Once I performed that bit of refactoring, I was able to compile the program and execute the program.  However, viewing the code I had some questions as to its traversal through the list structure.  It was evident that there were two elements in this linked list; however, only the second list element was being printed.  And, it appeared that the element ID was not going to its intended list element.  With that I added a bit of additional code within the linked list print function so that the initial linked list element could be viewed.  Following is a refactored version of your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct listen
{
    int id;
    int wert;

    char *namen;
    char *strasse;
    int plz;

    struct listen *next;
};

typedef struct listen elem;

void copyString(char *von, char *nach)
{
    while(*von!='\0')
    {
        *nach=*von;

        *von++;
        *nach++;
    }

    *nach = '\0';
}

elem *createElem(int id, int wert)
{
    elem* newElem = (elem*)malloc(sizeof(elem));

    if(newElem == NULL) printf("War nischt!\n");

    newElem->id = id;
    newElem->wert = wert;
    newElem->namen = NULL;
    newElem->strasse = NULL;
    newElem->plz = 0;

    return newElem;
}

int stringLen(char* len)
{
    int d=0;

    while(*len++) d++;

    return d;
}

char *createStr(char* st)
{
    char* newSt;

    newSt = (char*)malloc(stringLen(st)+1);

    if(newSt == NULL)
    {
        printf("Fehler\n");
    }

    copyString(st, newSt);

    return newSt;
}

void addToList(elem *list, int wert, char* namen, char* strasse, int plz)   /* FYI - made this a void function as the linked list pointer is already known and doesn't change */
{
    elem* p = createElem(list->id, wert);

    p->namen = createStr(namen);
    p->strasse = createStr(strasse);
    p->plz = plz;

    list->id++;
    p->next = list->next;
    list->next = p;

    return;
}

elem* createList()
{
    elem* liste = createElem(0, 0);

    return liste;
}

void printElem(elem *E)
{
    printf("ID: %d | Wert: %d | Name : %s | Strasse: %s | PLZ: %d\n", E->id, E->wert, E->namen, E->strasse, E->plz);
}

void printList(elem* list)
{
    printf("Liste:");
    printf("Data within initial list element\n");   /* Just to illustrate that the initial list element is not used */
    printElem(list);
    while(list->next != NULL)
    {
        printElem(list->next);
        list = list->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    elem* Liste01 = createList();

    addToList(Liste01, 4, "Peter", "Lustigweg", 15834);

    printList(Liste01);

    return 0;
}
```

With the extra printed information, following was the output at the terminal.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/DeutschList/bin/Release$ ./DeutschList 
Liste:Data within initial list element
ID: 1 | Wert: 0 | Name : (null) | Strasse: (null) | PLZ: 0
ID: 0 | Wert: 4 | Name : Peter | Strasse: Lustigweg | PLZ: 15834
```

As can be seen, the ID value is stored within the initial linked list element when the second linked list element is added; however, the other data elements went into the next linked list element.

I will leave you with refining the code so that the initial linked list element contains the initial data, but see if this moves you forward in the spirit of your project.